# Any licenses required for developing and selling Windows based c#. net application

Tags: .net

I have developed one desktop application in C# Net for one customer. I want to know, if I want to distribute this application to this customer as well as several other customers in future, which things or licenses I need to purchase like .net framework, visual studio etc.

You can consider that I am going to start my small software firm and going to make more of such applications and sell them to various customers.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it without paying any licensing fees, but this is a great resource that I am utilizing myself: https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/

Answer (score 4):

The .NET framework itself does not require you to purchase a licence, so there is no cost there.

As long as you are a solo developer you can use [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) at no charge, even if the programs you make with it are paid apps. Once you start your firm you may not be eligible for community edition anymore and may need to pay for a Visual Studio Professional licence per employee at your firm.

Any other 3rd party libraries you use in your projects is up to those libraries' licences if you need to pay any fee to develop or distribute them.